# How to return from AOP before method on validation failed

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to implement spring AOP @Before . 
Here is the method

```
 @Before("execution(* com.dummy.pkg..*.*(..))")
    public Response<Object> beforeServiceAspect(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {

            Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();

           String sessionId=(String) signatureArgs[0];


         if(null==sessionId||sessionId.isEmpty()||!loginService.getUserInfo(sessionId))
           {
                Response.setStatusCode("401");
                Response.setC
                Response.setResultString("Unauthorized User");
                  return  Response;    
 //this is where i  want to  return in case of program enter here   
//**point 1** 
           }
   //**point 2**  where execution reaches then resume normal flow 
return "";
}
```

Here is two thing i wanat to achieve

1. If flow reaches to point 1 then it return from that point itself.It should not go further and call should return back.
2. If flow reaches to point 2 , it resume normal flow and call internal method.
   what happening now is in both cases it flowing normal flow and keep calling internal methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `@Around` advice instead of a `@Before` advice, if you want to modify the control flow.

```
@Around("execution(* com.dummy.pkg..*.*(..))")
public Response<Object> beforeServiceAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {

        Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();

       String sessionId=(String) signatureArgs[0];


     if(null==sessionId || sessionId.isEmpty() || !loginService.getUserInfo(sessionId))
       {
            Response.setStatusCode("401");
            Response.setResultString("Unauthorized User");
            return  Response;    
       }
    return joinPoint.proceed(args);
}
```